# Add onclick event for MVC5 Url.Action

Tags: onclick, asp.net-mvc-5, url.action

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>Url.Action("GetOrderDetails", 
 new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort }),
  PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() 
   { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "gridTable" }))
```

I have the above code inside a MVC5 view.

**Question:** Is it possible to add a client-side onclick event handler for the above Url.Action generated URL by adding some extra parameter to Url.Action code? if yes, then where in Url.Action would I add this?

The HTML emitted by above PagedListPager is as below.

```
<ul class="pagination"><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" 
data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#gridTable" href="/Order_Details/GetOrderDetails?page=2&
amp;sortOrder=asc">2</a></li><li><a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace"
data-ajax-update="#gridTable" href="/Order_Details/GetOrderDetails?page=3&amp;sortOrder=asc">3</a>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: yes you can do ..you are using url.action with anchor tag or somewhere else??

Comment: Not with an anchor tag. I changed my code to show how I am using it. Its for Mvc PagedList component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.

This is because click events happen on *elements* in HTML, and `Url.Action` doesn't create an element.  It just emits a string.  If this string is *part* of an element, then you can add a click handler to that element.  For example, if you're doing this:

```
<a id="someLink" href="@Url.Action(parameters)">click here</a>
```

Then you can add a click handler in your client-side code.  ASP.NET MVC generally includes jQuery by default, so you can probably use that:

```
$('#someLink').click(function () {
    // handle the click here
});
```

> by adding some extra parameter to Url.Action code

As a general word of advice, you'll want to keep your server-side code and client-side code separate.  Your views have plenty of places to put client-side code, there's no need to pollute your server-side code with it.  And you'll find that your overall project becomes *a lot* easier to maintain if you keep your concerns separated.

**Edit:** You've updated the question, and it looks like you're using something called a `PagedListPager`.  I'm not familiar with this HTML helper, but presumably it emits some HTML markup to the page.  What is that markup?  *That* is what you'll use for your click handlers.  Again, your client-side click handlers operate on client-side code, not server-side code.  Best to separate the two.

Comment: I am using PagedList.Mvc package to get paging for a tabular data. So the modified code is part of this PagedList.Mvc helper, but it uses the MVC Url.Action as a parameter to PagedListPager method.

Comment: @Sunil: Ok.  Well, the principle is still the same.  HTML elements have click events, and you attach client-side handlers to those events in JavaScript.

Comment: I added the html markup emitted by this helper method in my post.

Comment: @Sunil: And which element needs its click element handled?  In a comment on the question say said you're not using an anchor tag, but in the posted markup you are in fact using an anchor tag.  Nothing about the answer has changed.  You just need to identify the HTML element whose click element you want to handle and attach the handler to it.

Comment: I can probably in ready event of jQuery look for all anchor elements within a div with pagination class and attach a onclick event handler for each anchor element.  But it seems quite messy this way.

Comment: All clickable anchor elements, since each anchor element is for a page number.

Comment: @Sunil: If that's how your elements are identified then it's not messy at all.  Once the DOM is ready you simply identify the element(s) and add the handler(s).

Comment: Ok. I guess since Ur.Action doesn't allow it then the jQuery ready event is the only way to go. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Sunil: Well, `Url.Action()` *can't* "allow it" because what you're trying to do isn't known to `Url.Action()`.  That method can't add a click handler to an HTML element when that method has no knowledge of HTML elements.  And even if there was some hack to try to achieve what you're asking, it would still be a bad idea to mix your server-side code and client-side code.